# Testing whether word is in list given from function

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

Im having trouble determining if a word given by the user is included in a list of words in a text file. Im not sure if I am properly transferring the words from the text file into a list through the function and comparing the userinput with the words in the list.

```
listtest = "listtest.txt"

def opentestfile(listtest):
    testlist = open(listtest,'r')
    line = [line.strip() for line in open(listtest)]
    print(line)
    testlist.close
    return testlist

opentestfile(listtest)

userinput2 = input("What word would you like to check? ")
if userinput2 in opentestfile(listtest):
    print("word is in file")
else:
    print("word is not in file")
```

Comment: What the specific nature of your "trouble"? Is it an exception? Or unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `line` instead. That's the list you should use.

```
def ...:
    return line
```

instead of

```
return testlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice try. However you made a few mistakes.

1. strip() is used to remove some characters from the string(blank by default). The correct function for divide a string into words is the split().
2. line = [line.split() for line in open(listtest)] will give you a list of lists which is not the behavior you want.
3. Your opentestfile() function returns a file pointer rather than the list you want.

So a slightly modified version will be:

```
listtest = "listtest.txt"

def opentestfile(listtest):
    testlist = open(listtest,'r')
    list = []
    for line in testlist:
        list += line.split()
    #print(line) You don't need this.
    testlist.close()
    return list

userinput2 = input("What word would you like to check? ")
if userinput2 in opentestfile(listtest):
    print("word is in file")
else:
    print("word is not in file")
```